# How does the High Impact Reserves perk interact with the Extended Mag mod?

Tags: destiny-2

I have a weapon which has High Impact Reserves, and I've placed an Extended Mag mod into it, boosting it's rounds from 36 to 42.

Will this give me more high impact rounds in the magazine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Hight Impact Reserves always works like this:

> The bottom half of the magazine deals extra damage, increasing as you
>   go deeper. The final round in the magazine deals 30% extra damage.

Thanks to the research people did on Reddit ([thread in question](https://www.reddit.com/r/DestinyTheGame/comments/9xzaj5/a_quick_overview_of_some_of_the_perks_in_destiny/)), we know that it combines with Extended Mag, but the damage cap is still at 30%:

> High-Impact Reserves tops out at 30% extra damage, regardless of how many you have in the magazine. Did some testing with a Tigerspite.
>
> Starting at 33 rounds, High-Impact Reserves will kick in when there are 16 rounds in the magazine. It hits for 108 crit damage
>   against a Trostland level enemy on the final round.
>
> With a Backup Mag mod, we start at 39 rounds. High-Impact Reserves kicks in when there are 19 rounds in the magazine. It also hits for
>   108 crit damage against a Trostland level enemy on the final round.
>
> The benefit is that you'll see increased damage longer. Have 50 rounds? 25 will deal increased damage. Up that to 100? 50 will deal
>   increased damage. The final round will always be the same, but you'll
>   do more damage per magazine the bigger it is.

Comment: So the effect lasts for more rounds, but requires firing more rounds at normal damage before it kicks in. And the additional damage increases more slowly. Unless you're emptying every magazine, this seems like a suboptimal combination.

Comment: @DavidHarkness Don't forget to factor in rate of fire!

Comment: @DavidYell Do Extended Mag or High Impact Reserves increase the rate-of-fire?

Comment: No, but it depends on the weapon frame into which you put the mod. A pulse rifle for example, versus an rapid fire auto rifle frame would change the speed at which you'd reach the high impact reserve part of the clip.

Comment: @DavidYell True, but that affects the RoF without the mod as well so my analysis still holds. You have to consider all stats when choosing whether to apply any weapon mod.

Answer (score 1):

While I cannot find a concrete number, [these patch notes](https://www.bungie.net/en/News/Article/47127) indicate that the perk provides a damage buff over a *percentage* of your magazine. Thus, logically, it would seem that a larger magazine size would give you more bullets with a damage boost as well.

Some players are theorizing about the perk, stating that there's a larger increase towards the end of the magazine (e.g. the first bullet with a damage boost provides a lower damage bonus than the final bullet in the magazine). There is some information about it in [this reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/DestinyTheGame/comments/8fzzo3/whats_the_total_damage_increase_from_having_high/). In this thread, they also assume that the **bottom half** of the magazine starts giving a damage boost to each bullet.